# How do I loop this array without warnings

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Due to restrictions in the joomla cms I had to think of a way to be able to add fields to a form on a productpage (for cakes).

So I came up with the following.

This is my starting string:

```
||
Taart grootte*30cm:40cm:50cm
|Kleur*rood:blauw:groen:wit
|Optie 3*optie1:optie2:optie3
```

I first explode on `||` to split my custom fields from the rest of the productpage. Then I explode on `|` to seperate each custom added field, then I explode that result on `*` to seperate the select options from the field names. All works well, but now I want to seperate the options from eachother by exploding on `:`.

The variable `$lines` contains the info I need. The array looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] =>

Taart grootte [1] => 30cm:40cm:50cm
) Array ( [0] => Kleur [1] => rood:blauw:groen:wit
) Array ( [0] => Optie 3 [1] => optie1:optie2:optie3

)
```

However I need only the data with key `[1]` (the options). I can't use :

```
foreach($lines[1] as $result){

}
```

Because it gives: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ....`

How can I split the options so that the data is useable for me?

I tried the following:

```
foreach($lines as $result){
    $resultaat = explode(':', $result);
}

foreach($resultaat as $final){
    $finalvar .= $final;
}
echo $finalvar;
```

But the result of that is this:

[image]

Same options displayed multiple times, while they are only once in the string.

My whole code:

```html
<?
// Functie om alles te deleten tussen de aangegeven values (brackets in deze code)
function delete_all_between($beginning, $end, $string) {
$beginningPos = strpos($string, $beginning);
$endPos = strpos($string, $end);
if ($beginningPos === false || $endPos === false) {
 return $string;
}

$textToDelete = substr($string, $beginningPos, ($endPos + strlen($end)) - $beginningPos);

return str_replace($textToDelete, '', $string);
}

// Explode the fulltext on ||
$explode = explode('||', $taartcr[0]['fulltext']);
if(strpos($explode[1], '[') == false){
echo '';
echo $explode[0];
echo '';

// Explode fulltext after || on commas
$explode2 = explode('|', $explode[1]);

$lijst .= '<div class="form-group">';

foreach($explode2 as $list){

 $lines = explode('*', $list);

  

  foreach($lines as $result){
 $resultaat = explode(':', $result);
  }

  foreach($resultaat as $final){
 $finalvar .= $final;
  }

  echo $finalvar;



  // echo $finalvar;


  // echo '<pre>';
 // // print_r($resultaat);
  // echo $resultaat;
 // echo '</pre>';



 if($list[0] != ''){
  $lijst .= '
 <i class="fa fa-birthday-cake cbx-contact-icon"></i>
 <select required="" placeholder="'.strip_tags($lines[0]).'" id="cbxname" class="form-control cbxname cbx-form-control" name="cbxname">
   <option value="" disabled selected>'.strip_tags($lines[0]).'</option>
   '.$resultaat.'
 </select>
  ';
 }
}
$lijst .= '</div>';
}else{
$string = $explode[1];
$nobrackets = delete_all_between('[', ']', $string);

echo '<div class="col-md-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s">'.strip_tags($explode[0]).'</div>';
echo '<div class="col-md-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s">'.strip_tags($nobrackets).'</div>';
}
echo $lijst;
?>
```

Edit for additional information on answer:

```
    <?php
$lines = explode( '||', $taartcr[0]['fulltext'] );
$lines = end( $lines );
$lines = explode( '|', $lines );

$options = [];

foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
  $result = explode( '*', $line );

  $name   = trim( $result[0] );
  $values = $result[1];

  $options[] = [
      'name'   => $name,
      'values' => array_map( 'trim', explode( ':', $values ) ),
  ];
}

foreach($options as $field){
$options1 = $field['values'];
foreach($options1 as $option){
  $test .= '<option>'.$option.'</option>';
}

$fields .= '
<div class="form-group">
    <i class="fa fa-birthday-cake cbx-contact-icon"></i><select required="" placeholder="'.$field['name'].'" id="cbxname" class="form-control cbxname cbx-form-control" name="cbxname">
      <option value="" disabled selected>'.$field['name'].'</option>
      '.$test.'
    </select>
    <label for="cbxname" class="error valid" id="cbxname-error"></label>
</div>';

}
echo $fields;
?>
```

Comment: Please replicate your problem here http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: @Ionut I'm trying by just using a hardcoded string and using that in my script but when I run the script I just see the php code echoed like no php is installed. Also have no idea where to get a shareable link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting yourself confused with all the different explodes and delimiters that are required. The snippet below will split everything into an `$options` array with two keys: `name`, which is a string containing the option name, and `values` which is an array of option values:

```
<?php

$str = "||
    Taart grootte*30cm:40cm:50cm
    |Kleur*rood:blauw:groen:wit
    |Optie 3*optie1:optie2:optie3";

$lines = explode( '||', $str );
$lines = end( $lines );
$lines = explode( '|', $lines );

$options = [];

foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
    $result = explode( '*', $line );

    $name   = trim( $result[0] );
    $values = $result[1];

    $options[] = [
        'name'   => $name,
        'values' => array_map( 'trim', explode( ':', $values ) ),
    ];
}

print_r( $options );
```

Sample `print_r` result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Taart grootte
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 30cm
                    [1] => 40cm
                    [2] => 50cm
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Kleur
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => rood
                    [1] => blauw
                    [2] => groen
                    [3] => wit
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Optie 3
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => optie1
                    [1] => optie2
                    [2] => optie3
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Awesome, the code is a lot cleaner now! But how can I make sure the values are only shown once per selectbox? I added the code I use in my question. When I use `$test = '<option>'.$option.'</option>';` there is only one option shown for each select element. And when I add a dot before the = sign, the first select box has the correct options, but the second one has all the options of the first and his own options, this continues on for every following select element.

Comment: You need to loop through the `values` array of each option. So you'll need a loop within a loop.

Comment: I am doing that but still every new field has all the values of the previous fields. I got the exact same code as in my question (the bottom part).

Comment: That's because you're overwriting the value of the `$options` variable at the beginning of your loop.

Comment: Makes sense, I renamed the variables but still the same result. Maybe I misunderstood you but you meant the variable just before my last loop right (and the looped array variable itself ofcourse)?

Comment: I'm out at the moment and replying on my phone. Will have a look on my desktop when I get home in about 30 minutes :)

Comment: I fixed it by unsetting `$test` so I'll accept your answer, thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see what your issue was. Unsetting `$test` works, but you just needed a `$test = ''` at the beginning of the first loop so as to wipe the option values from the previous loop.